# Problema em struct

Tags: c

Galera, pq o meu printf não está pegando o "tempo" da struct? ele está mostrando um valor aleatório. Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct cadastro{
    char nome[30];
    int idade;
    int ano;
    int nmatricula;
    int tempo;
    float salario;
};
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct cadastro colaborador [2];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("Entre com o nome do colaborador: \n");
    scanf("%s",&colaborador[i].nome);
    printf("Entre com a idade: \n");
    scanf("%d",&colaborador[i].idade);
    printf("Entre com o numero da matricula: \n");
    scanf("%d",&colaborador[i].nmatricula);
    printf("Entre com o tempo na empresa: \n");
    scanf("%f",&colaborador[i].tempo);
    printf("Insira o salario: \n");
    scanf("%f",&colaborador[i].salario);
    printf("nome: %s\n",colaborador[i].nome);
    printf("idade %d\n",colaborador[i].idade);
    printf("numero da matricula %d\n",colaborador[i].nmatricula);
    printf("tempo na empresa %d\n",colaborador[i].tempo);
    printf("o salario foi %.2f\n",colaborador[i].salario);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: No scanf, use ```%d``` para a leitura de inteiros. ```%f``` é para floats. Acredito que isso deva resolver

Comment: Não vejo você definindo os valores dos campos da struct antes de usar.

Answer (score 0):

Na hora de ler o valor de `colaborador[i].tempo`, você utiliza `%f`, o que só pode ser utilizado para valores do tipo Float. Como a propriedade do Objeto cadastro foi declarado como tipo Int, você deve utilizar `%d`. Lembrando,

```
Char - <i>%c<i>
String - <i>%s<i>
Int - <i>%d<i>
Float - <i>%f<i>
Double - <i>%lf<i>
```

Esses são os tipos primitivos de variáveis mais comuns e seus respectivos "códigos".

Answer (score -1):

Olá! No seu código eu notei 2 problemas:
1- quando se lê uma string em: "scanf("%s",&colaborador[i].nome);" não se usa "&", uma vez que, você não está armazenando um caractere em especifico em uma posição especifica da memoria e sim um conjunto de caracteres em cada posição do vetor.
2 - no que se refere ao tempo em: "scanf("%f",&colaborador[i].tempo);", note que você usou %f em vez de %d ou %i já que na estrutura a variável é do tipo int.